# Ferramenta de build automático para Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

**Existem aplicações para build automático, como o `FinalBuilder`, e que seja `Free` ou `Open-Source`?**
De preferência que suporte versões antigas e novas do **Delphi**.
**Quais seriam estes?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abaixo indico ferramentas de CI (integração contínua). Não é exatamente o que você pediu, mas se você não é um desenvolvedor trabalhando sozinho, recomendo muito que você use uma ferramenta deste tipo. Elas fazem o build automático, podem monitorar seu repositório e iniciar builds automaticamente, etc.

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/): Free e open source.
- [Continua CI](http://www.finalbuilder.com/continua-ci): Possui uma versão inicial free que atende bem a pequenas equipes. Esse é o que eu uso e tem atendido bem. Suporte muito bom.
- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/): Possui versão inicial free.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o MSBuild para compilar qualquer versão do delphi pois ele irá realizar a compilação por linha de comando.

segue um overview com mais dados para utilizar o build pelo MSBuild neste **[link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/MSBuild_Overview)** da propria embarcadero (pois para colocar o conteúdo inteiro seria um enorme manual )

Comment: Delphi7 também? E as Library do projeto, não fica mais complicado?